# What exactly the effect of the viewport meta on elements width?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I read a w3school tutorial about viewport meta tag, so they give 2 examples to explain the usage of the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The [first example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/example_withoutviewport.htm) one without it shows as expected, while [the second example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/example_withviewport.htm) with the tag adjust the image width on smartphones making it 100% the viewport width, witch doesn't make sense to me. Why would setting the virtual width equal to the device width make that kind of adjustment, the image shouldn't normally fit the whole width in both cases as it's set width of 460px is smaller than my device width of more than 1000px and a wider virtual width.

My second inquiry is about initial-scale=1, shouldn't that be the default value, what would be different if we didn't declare it.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the CSS for that page.

> ```
> img {
>     max-width: 100%;
>     height: auto;
> }
> ```

The max-width overrides the width.

Comment: I saw it, but max-width should have any effect if the width is smaller than the max width witch is 100%=1000px, am i wrong?

Comment: @habibhassani — 100% is the width of the display. That won't be 1000px on a phone.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be, my phone display width is more than 1000px;

Comment: You might be confusing CSS pixels with display pixels. They have never been the same. The variations are a lot higher with the high resolution displays we have on modern phones.

Comment: Ok thank you, that's explain it, i check it and it's 360px.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Quentin's answer,

If you set the initial scale to "1.0" then the web page is displayed to match the resolution of the target density 1-to-1.

Comment: Can you give an example please?